# Identify device across different computers

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I read here:

https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB53715&cat=CORP_DATA_LOSS_PREVENTION_HOST&actp=LIST

that the HID, PID, VID and the GUID are embedded in the hardware of the device.

so does the following make sense:

1. I take a USB keyboard, plug it into my computer.
2. I read out the HID, PID, VID and the GUID of the device, and save it somewhere.
3. I send this HID, PID, VID and the GUID to my friends computer.
4. My friend plugs in a USB keyboard.
5. If the HID, PID, VID and the GUID match, then we have the same type of keyboard, it could even be the same keyboard, if it does not match, then we do not have the keyboard type.

I'm asking this because I want to differentiate between different keyboards across different computers, is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. If PID & VID matches - it is the same type of keyboard. If everything matches - it is the same keyboard.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I have two USB Keyboards attached to my laptop, (Well, one's a scanner, but registers itself as a keyboard). And they both have the the *same* GUIDs, same PIDs, but different VIDs. Plus, the keyboard on my laptop doesn't have a PID & VID but it does have a GUID, and the GUID matches the Guids of my two USB keyboards.

Comment: It is designed to be so: VID is a Vendor ID and it is unique across the World to differentiate vendors. It is supposed that PID will be assigned by vendors to different products. But no one may stop one vendor make two devices having the same PID.